# Getting the correct SQL subquery where nested select statement has been used

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, subquery

I have a table named Employee which has the following columns:

```
ID(primary key) of type int
Name of type varchar(255)
Designation of type varchar(50)
Salary of type int
```

I want to write a sub-query, which will give me the names of the employees who have greater salary than ANY employee of the designation 'Junior Officer'.

Here's what I have tried but was unsuccessful:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Employee
WHERE Salary> 
(SELECT Salary FROM Employee WHERE Designation = 'Junior Officer');
```

Comment: Did you try `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`?

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik `HAVING` is for `GROUP BY`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is @RacilHilan

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik So how are you recommending him to use it instead of `WHERE` while he does not have `GROUP BY` in his query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is urgent, I'm writing you this without testing it. Try this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Employee
WHERE Salary > 
(SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee WHERE Designation = 'Junior Officer');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
    SELECT Name
FROM Employee
WHERE Salary> 
(SELECT max(Salary) FROM Employee WHERE Designation = 'Junior Officer');
```